# Step Function For Array in Anylogic

Tags: arrays, function, anylogic

How to use an step function for an array in Anylogic?
step function is applied to double values, but I want to applied on elements of an array at a specific time.

Answer (score 0):

You can't... so this is a solution:

Instead of an array you should use a linkedHashMap where your key is the specific time and the element is the step value you want at that time. So you defined it as follow:

[image: linkedHashMap]

And you put the values like this:

```
stepsArray.put(3.0,2.3);
```

where 3.0 is the time in which the step will occur and 2.3 is the value the step will take. You have to put there all the values you need. You are the one who has to fill these values according to your needs.

Then you create an cyclic event that will evaluate if it's time to apply a step and you create a variable of type double that will be the one storing the value of the step.

So, the event:

```
double theTime=round(100*time())/100.0;//it's better to round up the time just in case
if(stepsArray.containsKey(theTime)){
    variable=stepsArray.get(theTime);
}
```

note that I'm using a variable, not a dynamic variable.. they you can connect the variable to wherever your step is needed in the sd model.

This method is a bit complicated, but it's the most general for your completely ambiguous question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure Felipe's approach is the best one but maybe I misunderstand the question.

Have you tried using a "table function" object? Define it as below where the horizontal axis represents the time unit and the vertical your step function data:
[image]

Then, use a cyclic event that every relevant time unit (depends on your model) pulls the current required value from the table function:
[image]

Comment: This is a good answer, and to use arrays as the questions states you can use myTableFunction.setArgumentsAndValues(timeArray, valueArray); and you don't need the myEvent, instead you will have a dynamicVariable equals to myTableFunction(time()) ... and with out of range=Nearest would be better in most cases

Comment: Love it... great answer